# Artix-7 SATA implementation using LiteSATA won't initialize

Tags: fpga, xilinx, sata, artix-series-fpga, hdd

I am trying to run the [LiteSATA bench file provided for the Nexys Video](https://github.com/enjoy-digital/litesata/blob/master/bench/nexys_video.py) (Artix-7 xc7a200t-sbg484-1). The board is new and does not have anything connected to it, and I am building / loading the bitstream to the FPGA with the following over USB programming interface:

`./nexys_video.py --pll-refclk --build --load` from the `/litex/litesata/bench` directory.

Since there is no external clock provided for the transceiver, I am attempting to use the internal 150 MHz PLL reference clock which as been documented to work by others using LiteSATA. I have tried building this bench file with both Gen 1 and Gen2 SATA. The bitstream is built and loaded successfully using the Vivado toolchain over OpenOCD, however once the bitstream starts on the FPGA, only a single LED0 lights up, signifying that the TX, RX, and Ready signals are never initialized. I am unsure as to why SATA does not initialize, is an external 150MHz clock required for this specific FPGA? Does a hard drive need to be attached to the SATA RX/TX lines for the SATA core to initialize?

[The terminal output for the compilation and build can be found here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/md-raz/experiments/main/misc/terminal_output-Nexys_Video.txt). Please let me know if there is a solution discernible from this, or if more information is needed.

Comment: Did you do any measurement using an oscilloscope? How do you know your PLL is locked and at the right frequency? is there any digital signal between your FPGA and HDD?

Comment: What board are you using? It isn't enough to just tell us the part number of the FPGA. Also, the part number you gave ('xc7a200t-sbg484-1') doesn't exist. Are you sure you didn't mean xc7a200t-1sbg484i-1 ?